# Mediawiki Hyperswitch: Return if some value in the response body equals to a variable

Tags: javascript, rest, mediawiki

I am using [RestAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/REST_API) from Wikibase which in turn use [Hyperswitch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HyperSwitch) framework.

In the example code of its yaml file, there is a case to choose to return the response or not depend on the status code

```
 x-request-handler:
        - storage:
            request:
              method: get
              headers:
                cache-control: '{{cache-control}}'
#                cache-control: "no-cache"
              uri: /{domain}/sys/key_value/page_summary3/{request.params.title}
            catch:
              status: 404
            return_if:
              # Typical case: Return straight from storage.
              status: '2xx'
            return:
```

But I would like to return depend on a value found on the response body, say `success: 1`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
return_if:
    '{{storage.body.success}}': 1
```

maybe? That syntax works in values, I don't know if it works in keys. You can always handle the request manually though: use `operationId` instead of `x-request-handler`, and then have a function like

```
function storage(hyper, req) {
    return hyper.get(...).then((res) => {
        if (res.body.success === 1) {
            return res;
        }
        return {...};
    });
}
```

and export it with the operation ID you chose.